# succesfully changed order regions in info file, but rendered html stays untouched

Tags: 7

Layout-wise I want 3 columns in this order: `sidebar first - content - sidebar right`. Since the region order in d7 is `content - sidebar first - sidebar second` I wanted to change that order in html.

If I remember well, all that's needed to change the order of the regions, is to do that in the `.info` file.

So I simply just put the `content` region between `sidebar first` and `sidebar second` so the info file has the following in it:

```
regions[header] = Header
regions[highlighted] = Highlighted
regions[help] = Help
regions[sidebar_first] = Left sidebar
regions[content] = Content
regions[sidebar_second] = Right sidebar
regions[footer] = Footer
```

When I go to `structure` -> `blocks` The result that I'm seeings is what I was aiming for; the content region is being replaced. Yet, when I go and check the HTML,The order remains `content - sidebar first - sidebar second`.

Goes without saying I cleared caches often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the orders of your regions are probably defined in the `page.tpl.php` of your current theme. so you will have to change the order there, changing the order of your .info entries should (if any) only change the output from configuration pages.

Comment: Now that I performed this override you mentioned, it dawned on me that I alwas did that.